# If match is found between two columns, create third column with value of match, if no match create fourth column with value of non-match

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula or script that will categorize a respondents answer and am not sure about the best way to do this.

Essentially, I have a list of my students in column A, and a list of all school students who would like to attend events (for extra credit, heh) in Column B. I am hoping to set up an if/then or match based on the responses (so if one of the requestors is a student of mine, their name gets copied into column C, if they are a guest, their name gets copied into column D).

I'm getting references and n/a errors in my attempt: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A2MfkRxx4g_J6ZFkjzRC6Q_5jL0g-0VEIyKK13XENXw/edit#gid=0

Thank you in advance for your consideration

Comment: So you want to check if value in B exists in column A. If so, value in B should be copied to column C, otherwise copied to column D? You can use this in C2: `=IFERROR(vlookup(B2,A$2:A,1,false),"")` and this in D2: `=if(C2="",B2,"")`

Comment: Thank you so much Casper. When I do that, cell d2 is blank, when I'm trying to get it to say Molly. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Lou, this method will determine per value in column B whether it is a student or guest and place it in the respective column. In order to create two columns that create a list of all students and guests without empty cells in between you would probably need to use a VBA script.

Answer (score 1):

To force the names to be continuously adjacent, put this Array formula in C2 and copy down as needed:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$5,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$8,B$2:B$8)>0,ROW(B$2:B$8),""),ROW()-1)),"")
```

In D2, this formula and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$5,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$8,B$2:B$8)=0,ROW(B$2:B$8),""),ROW()-1)),"")
```

Both are entered with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.